# Complex firebase read query - String, Float, Int and NSArray

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull out a lot of variables from `Firebase`. Not all of these will have any content. I therefore need to be able to handle nil and at the same time convert to the required data type (eg. Float and Int)

**Currently I'm getting error on the first Float "distance":**

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**A few questions:**

1. How can a make the Float conversion handle potential nil cases
2. Im thinking of storing the Float as a String in Firebase, rather than wrapping it in NSNumber. Do you agree?
3. If in the app I only need eg. 5 of the below variables, should I then make a specific query for this - or is typically no big cost to get all variables in one go?
4. Have I made the Array or Map (Dictionary) elements (eg. likes, comments, imageURLs) correct?

**Code:**

```
    // Get data on all activities
    func getAllFeedActivities(handler: @escaping (_ activities: [Activity]) -> (Void)) {
        var activityArray = [Activity]()        


        REF_ACTIVITY.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (feedActivitySnapshot) in

            guard let feedActivitySnapshot = feedActivitySnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }


            for activity in feedActivitySnapshot {

                let activityId =            activity.key as String
                let name =                  activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? ""
                let description =           activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value as? String ?? ""

                let userId =                activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "userId").value as? String ?? ""
                let type =                  activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "type").value as? String ?? ""
                let gearId =                activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "gearId").value as? String ?? ""

                let distance =              Float(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "distance").value as? String ?? "") as! Float                          // In meters
                let totalElevationGain =    Float(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "totalElevationGain").value as? String ?? "") as! Float                // In meters
                let elevationHigh =         Float(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "elevationHigh").value as? String ?? "") as! Float                     // In meters                         
                let elevationLow =          Float(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "elevationLow").value as? String ?? "") as! Float                      // In meters

                let startTime =             activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "startTime").value as? String ?? ""                                          // Unix time - seconds
                let timeZone =              activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeZone").value as? String ?? ""
                let movingTime =            Int(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "movingTime").value as? String ?? "") as! Int                            // In seconds
                let elapsedTime =           Int(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "elapsedTime").value as? String ?? "") as! Int                           // In seconds


                let likeCount =             Int(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "likeCount").value as? String ?? "") as! Int
                let likes =                 activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "likes").value as? NSArray ?? [""]
                let commentCount =          Int(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "commentCount").value as? String ?? "") as! Int
                let comments =              activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments").value as? NSArray ?? [""]
                let imageCount =            Int(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "imageCount").value as? String ?? "") as! Int
                let imageURLs =             activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "imageURLs").value as? NSArray ?? [""]
                let defaultImageURL =       activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "defaultImageURL").value as? String ?? ""

                let activity = Activity(activityId: activityId, name: name, description: description, userId: userId, type: type, gearId: gearId, distance: distance, totalElevationGain: totalElevationGain, elevationHigh: elevationHigh, elevationLow: elevationLow, startTime: startTime, timeZone: timeZone, movingTime: movingTime, elapsedTime: elapsedTime, likeCount: likeCount, likes: likes as! Array<String>, commentCount: commentCount, comments: comments as! Array<String>, imageCount: imageCount, imageURLs: imageURLs as! [String], defaultImageURL: defaultImageURL)
                activityArray.append(activity)
            }
            handler(activityArray)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more consistent to declare the attributes as much as possible with a default value (non-optional). Obviously you are responsible for the design of the database but your code looks like you are more guessing than knowing. For example a syntax `Float(activity.childSnapshot(forPath: "distance").value as? String ?? "") as! Float` is hilarious. And do not use `NSArray` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system.

Comment: @vadian: Yes I'm only few months into coding, so Im definitely a n00b. So far I've come to understand strings fairly well, but today is my first try on Float, Int and Arrays. 

I've done some reading and I felt (until your comment) that the data types was the correct ones for my purpose. But definitely open for input. 

The reason for the force downcast, is that Xcode either requires it where I've put it, or later as part of the "let activity = Activity(..". I found it odd, that is why I've posted the question.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you want to assign a default value and the value is supposed to be

- `String` use `.value as? String ?? ""`
- `Int` use `.value as? Int ?? 0`
- `Float` use `.value as? Float ?? 0.0`
- `Double` use `.value as? Double ?? 0.0`
- `Bool` use `.value as? Bool ?? false`
- `Array` use `.value as? [String] ?? []` // where `String` must be the expected array type
- `Dictionary` use `.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]`

In case of `Array` and `Dictionary` you have to annotate the type if it's not declared before

```
let imageURLs : [String] = ...
```

However I recommend to declare the attributes with default values already in the database then the values can never be nil and you can force unwrap them.

---

Answers to your other questions:

2) No, use always the appropriate type.

3) Yes, a specific query is more efficient, to handle always all values is more expensive.

4) See 1) - Do not use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift.